# How to add a summary row at bottom of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to have a summary row that shows the refreshdate, blank in Naics code column, 'Total' title in industry column, weighted average of the weighted average duration column, and the sum of each column left.

I have tried using UNION ALL, but kept running into issues.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    GETDATE() AS 'RefreshDate',
    NaicsID AS 'NAICS Code',
    NaicsName AS 'Industry',
    FORMAT(SUM(RemainingTerm * BaseRent)/SUM(BaseRent), 'N1') AS 'Weighted Average Duration',
    FORMAT(SUM(BaseRent), 'C0') AS 'Occupied Contract Rent',
    FORMAT(SUM(BaseRent)/(SELECT SUM(BaseRent) 
                          FROM dbo.data 
                          WHERE NextSpaceLeaseID IS NULL), 'P1') AS '% of Commercial Total Rent',
    FORMAT(SUM(SpaceLeaseArea), 'N0') AS 'Occupied SF',
    FORMAT(SUM(SpaceLeaseArea)/(SELECT SUM(SpaceLeaseArea) 
                                FROM dbo.data 
                                WHERE NextSpaceLeaseID IS NULL), 'P1') AS '% of Commercial Total SF'
INTO
    industryExposure
FROM 
    dbo.data
WHERE 
    NaicsID NOT LIKE '%[Legacy Lease]%' 
    AND NextSpaceLeaseID IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    NaicsID, NaicsName;
```

Comment: Have you researched `rollup`?

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. Some methods of using single quotes for Aliases are deprecated and only works when you define them, no where else; `ORDER BY 'Quantity'` would *not* order by your column aliased as `'Quantity'`. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Considering all the `FORMAT` calls above, it *looks like* you're trying to do the job of the presentation/reporting layer in the SQL layer. Perhaps you would be better off doing the totalling and formatting in the presentation layer (certainly the formatting should be)

Comment: @Austin yes into the inudstryExposure table

Comment: `… GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((NaicsID, NaicsName), ())`

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `GROUPING SETS` for this.** The `GROUPING()` function tells you if a column has been grouped or not.

Further notes:

- You can refactor the two sub-queries into a single `CROSS JOIN`. Conditional aggregation may be even faster, but I have left that to you.
- It's unclear why you think you need `DISTINCT`, given that you are grouping anyway.
- The two columns which divide by the subquery values may not give expected results, you may need to calculate the division some other way. I don't have sample data and expected results so I don't know what you need
- Do *not* use `''` to quote column names, instead use `[]`

```sql
SELECT
    GETDATE() AS RefreshDate,
    d.NaicsID AS [NAICS Code],
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(d.NaicsName) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE d.NaicsName END AS Industry,
    FORMAT(SUM(d.RemainingTerm * d.BaseRent) / SUM(d.BaseRent), 'N1') AS [Weighted Average Duration],
    FORMAT(SUM(d.BaseRent), 'C0') AS [Occupied Contract Rent],
    FORMAT(SUM(d.BaseRent) / v.Total, 'P1') AS [% of Commercial Total Rent],
    FORMAT(SUM(d.SpaceLeaseArea), 'N0') AS [Occupied SF],
    FORMAT(SUM(d.SpaceLeaseArea) / v.Total, 'P1') AS [% of Commercial Total SF]
INTO
    industryExposure
FROM 
    dbo.data d
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(d2.SpaceLeaseArea) AS Total
    FROM dbo.data d2
    WHERE d2.NextSpaceLeaseID IS NULL
) v
WHERE 
    d.NaicsID NOT LIKE '%[Legacy Lease]%' 
    AND d.NextSpaceLeaseID IS NULL
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (d.NaicsID, d.NaicsName, v.Total),
    ()
);
```